# How do you go about conducting business internationally?

Tags: international

I have a few questions on this topic. Let's assume the following:

- Company A is based in China and Company B is based in Mexico.
- Company A has no presence in Mexico. Company B has no presence in China. Company A wants to pay Company B for its service.
- Company A and Company B will be signing an agreement to formally
  establish their working relationship.
- Company A wants legal protection over this deal, i.e. Company A might
  sue Company B if necessary.

Given this,

1. Is Company A required to have an entity in Mexico to enforce its legal rights?
2. Should the contract signed by both parties be a contract based on the local laws of Mexico?
3. If your answer to both of the questions above is "Yes", can this process be scaled? (Company A wanting to repeat this process with other companies from different countries)

Comment: The answer almost certainly depends on the jurisdiction in which the service will be provided, and perhaps also on the nature of the service, neither of which is specified.

Comment: The service will be provided online. The nature of the service is running an advertising campaign on a social media platform

Comment: "Online" is not a place with jurisdiction and laws.

Comment: @Nij true, but we can now understand how a company provides a service for another company when those companies have no presence in any common jurisdiction, and we can also assume that the service provider will be working in Mexico.

Answer (score 3):

1. No. A plaintiff may travel to the defendant's jurisdiction to file suit if desired. Nobody usually does this, though, due to travel and logistical considerations. The defendant is the one who decides whether to challenge jurisdiction.
2. Good contacts will include a forum selection clause which would lay out what happens where in the event of a dispute. And this can be anywhere, it is not limited to the locations of the plaintiff and the defendant.
3. N/A.

Comment: Item 2 requires the contract have some connection with the contract - usually one of the parties locations or the place where the contract takes place. You can’t nominate French law if the contract has nothing to do with France - French courts will tell you to get lost.

Comment: In addition - such nominations are always subject to judicial review and are non-exclusive

Comment: Forum selection is the right way to go. Financial contract often use England but Switzerland or the Netherlands might also work.  You need countries  where judges and lawyers are used to international cases, and where treaties are in place to get judgements enforced. Have a local lawyer check  which country has workable treaties with both China and Mexico.

Comment: Not true, @DaleM. To invalidate a forum selection clause, the clause must deprive the party of his day in court. See Bremen v. Zapata 407 US 1 (1972). There, there was a contract between a Houston company and a German company to transport equipment from the US to Italy. The clause set London as venue. The Supreme Court held the clause was enforceable based on the strength of a negotiated contract. In international business, this happens all the time. Companies from all over set London, Paris, New York, etc. as the forum for a variety of reasons, particularly the institutions available there.

Comment: The more pressing problem for @Dalem is that France is a signatory to the Hague Choice of Court Convention. The French court has no choice. And as it happens, so are China and Mexico

Answer (score 1):

1. No. 2. It depends 3. It depends

First of all, you should **seek advice from a lawyer that specializes in bridging the gap between the two jurisdictions** involved. This is important. A regular lawyer from your home jurisdiction will be unfamiliar with the various pitfalls you will encounter abroad, and a lawyer from the foreign jurisdiction may take for granted what you aren't aware of, so he may not explain the pitfalls you'll run into either.

As a general rule, you should be using **well-written contracts that include a choice of forum court clause and a governing law clause**.

Choice of forum clauses can be tricky because a court in another jurisdiction might apply its own laws to it and declare the clause void ... and voilà you end up in a foreign court.

You will have to choose which laws will apply to the contract. At the first glance, it will seem that keeping governing law and forum court in your own country is the better option. However, agreeing to a foreign governing law and a foreign forum court also comes with advantages: Your partner will have a clear understanding of the obligations that arise from the contract and suing your customer would be quite straight-forward. The opposite case (customer sues you) would be more difficult because he would have to file suit in his own jurisdiction, but service, domestication and enforcement would have to be made internationally.

Another issue with choice of forum clauses is that if a claim is being dismissed for being filed in the wrong jurisdiction, you may have to pay the fees for your own lawyer because the lex fori don't entitle you to fee recovery. I would include a clause in the contract that allows you to sue for damage compensation in the right jurisdiction if this case arises.

When doing business with China in particular, there are certain pitfalls you should be aware of, such as:

• China doesn't enforce foreign court judgements, although this may change in the near future.
• Large payments from China to other countries require government approval and are subject to taxation.
• International process service from other countries to China tends to be slow.

For further reading about doing business with China, I suggest this blog: https://www.chinalawblog.com/